# TabBar with circular, scrollable and focus on center in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Can I make a similar TabBar in flutter. (https://github.com/EndouMari/TabPageViewController)
[image]

Comment: Did you try PageView? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Comment: Depends on your skills :)

Comment: Did you find any way? I want to do the same, and my Tabs in TabBar have different width.